# Rename column of one table based on value of a row in another table

Tags: oracle11g, toad

For example I have two tables - Table1 and Table2

Table1 with columns Q1,Q2 and Q3.

```
Q1  Q2  Q3 Map_id
11  23  34  11101
22  22  22  11102
```

Table2 with column refvalue, actualvalue

```
refvalue    actualvalue     Map_id
    Q1  Remaining           11101
    Q2  Utilized        11101
    Q3  Actual          11101
    Q1  Remaining1      11102
    Q2  Utilized1   11102
    Q3  Actual1 11102
```

Now i want  to replace column_name of Table1 to corresponding value in Table2.

Example :

```
select Q1 as "Remaining", Q2 as "Utilized", Q3 as "Actual"
from Table1;
```

Now this is hard coded, how to make it logical ? I have no idea how to approach this and I am new in oracle.

Version : Oracle11g
Client : Toad

Comment: This is bad relations design! You should change this.

Comment: @sagi - This is business requirement. We cant change it. This is how Client legacy system is and they dont want it to change. Can you help me with the solution ?

Comment: So you should add another column for relations, this will raise a lot of errors in the future! This can be done with `PL/SQL` but without being able to join the tables properly, it will be a long a unreadable code!

Comment: @sagi - sorry i missed one more detail. Adding in the question

Answer (score 1):

Although this is very bad relations design and I advise you to change it, it can be done with `PL/SQL` , something like this:(maybe adjust it a little bit)

```
select 'SELECT Q1 as '||MAX(CASE WHEN t2.ref_value = 'Q1' THEN t2.actual_value END)||',
               Q2 as '||MAX(CASE WHEN t2.ref_value = 'Q2' THEN t2.actual_value END)||',
               Q3 as '||MAX(CASE WHEN t2.ref_value = 'Q3' THEN t2.actual_value END)
        ||'FROM Table1'
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON(1=1)
```

This will generate the sql you need

Comment: This does not give values of column. Anyways i updated the question as well.

Comment: @AnkurVerma This isn't supposed to bring values,the out put it generates is an sql code that you need to copy and execute, then you'll have your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a log table, DDL_LOG_TAB.
2. Loop through the records in Table2 using implicit cursor.
3. For each record in Table2, build a string statement, "ALTER TABLE TABLE1 RENAME COLUMN rec.refvalue TO rec.actualvalue" where rec refers each record in the implicit cursor.
4. Inside the loop, insert each of the generated statement into DDL_LOG_TAB.

Now you have all the required DDLs in your new DDL_LOG_TAB. Just select the SQL and execute it as a dynamic SQL.

You may even improvise this new table to hold execution timestamps (start and end TS), error message or success flag. In future you can use this table for,

a. Generating and executing any kind of DDLs.
b. Referring past history of DDLs executed in chronological order.
c. If any DDL errors out and execution stops, you can fix the error and restart the execution right from the point of failure.

Hope this helps now and also in the future. Good luck.

Comment: He didn't ask to change the column names, he asked to select them `AS`